# Python-AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to count the word on the google homepage. But I got AttributeError on the initial stage.

My code is -->

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def main(url):
    word_list=[]
    source_code=requests.get(url).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code,'lxml')
    for post_text in soup.findAll('a'):
        content=post_text.string
        words=content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)

main('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=2-nqWavnB4WN8Qf4n7eQAw')
```

My Output is -->

```
images
maps
play
youtube
news
gmail
drive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_freq.py", line 18, in <module>
    main('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=2-nqWavnB4WN8Qf4n7eQAw')
  File "word_freq.py", line 13, in main
    words=content.lower().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: You need to add an `if content is not None`  after `content=post_text.string`, since it is not necessary that all `a` tags have text string.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are parsing a web page in html so you need

   soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code,'html.parser')
2. string is the incorrect attribute to get the content of any tag, use text:

   content=post_text.text